# SwiftUI - Updating FocusState from onChange

Tags: swift, swiftui, focus, onchange

I need to set the FocusState to nil (or if I have to, another value) in an onChange modifier of a Picker in a macOS app (build for 13.3).

This should be so simple, but the code below does not work. The console output of the print isFocused statement shows the current isFocused value instead of showing nil. You can test this by clicking into one of the text fields and then changing the value of the picker to get the print to console output.

I have tried wrapping the isFocused = nil call in a DispatchQueue.main.async { isFocused = nil }, I have tried adding delays, booleans, etc. Nothing works and I'm at a loss.

When the picker value changes, isFocused must be nil before the other code (not shown) that is within the onChange modifier is run. Hoping I just overlooked something simple.

```
struct MyTestView: View {

    enum Field: Hashable {
        case field1
        case field2
    }
    
    @State private var myArray = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    @State private var myPickerVar: String? = "One"
    @FocusState var isFocused: MyView.Field?

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $myPickerVar.animation()) {
               ForEach(myArray, id: \.self) { option in
                   Text(option)
                       .tag(Optional(option))
               }
            } label: {
                Text("My Picker")
            }
            .onChange(of: myPickerVar ?? "") { option in
                isFocused = nil
                print("Focused: \(String(describing: isFocused))")
            }

            TextField("", $myTextVar)
                .focused($isFocused, equals: .field1)

            TextField("", $myTextVar2)
                .focused($isFocused, equals: .field2)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation for [`FocusState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate) says:

> When focus enters the modified view, the wrapped value of this property updates to match a given prototype value. Similarly, when focus leaves, the wrapped value of this property resets to `nil` or `false`. Setting the property’s value programmatically has the reverse effect, causing focus to move to the view associated with the updated value.

The value of `isFocused` only changes to `nil` *when focus leaves*. It is reasonable to believe that the focus does not immediately leave *as soon as* you set it to nil. Some time is needed for the views to update. Also, `FocusState` is a property wrapper, so it is entirely possible for its setter to not update the wrapped value immediately.

The setter of a property wrapped by a property wrapper can even do nothing at all, or run any arbitrary code instead.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct SetterDoesNothing<T> {
    private var value: T
    init(wrappedValue: T) { value = wrappedValue }
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get { value }
        set { /* do nothing! */ }
    }
}
```

Instead of wrapping the assignment with `DispatchQueue.main.async`, wrap whatever code you have below instead.

```
isFocused = nil
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // this prints nil
    print("Focused: \(String(describing: isFocused))")
}
```

Alternatively, detect the change of `isFocused` with `onChange` too:

```
.onChange(of: isFocused) { newValue in
    if newValue == nil {
        // do your things...
    }
}
```

Comment: Focus leaves immediately when set to nil everywhere that you can actually set a focused modifier. The issue is that setting it programmatically doesn't seem to work. I even tried creating a custom binding variable with a get/set so that I can perform an action when the picker value is clicked. I can see a print statement in console, but the isFocused variable is never set (nil or otherwise).

Comment: Btw, doing it exactly like this is how I do this in iOS all the time without any issue. macOS is apparently different which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @kittonian "Focus leaves immediately" How did you observe this? Can you be *sure* that it leaves by the time the `print` in the next line runs? I can confidently tell you that is not what happens. Try putting some break points. I cannot reproduce what you expect on iOS either. The same behaviour can be observed on iOS.

Comment: @kittonian "The issue is that setting it programmatically doesn't seem to work" Doesn't that contradict your previous statement of "focus leaves immediately"? As I suggested in the answer, you can just use `onChange(of: isFocused)` instead. That's how you are supposed to observe changes. What's wrong with `onChange(of: isFocused)` anyway? Why do you insist on being able to observe the change in the very next line? To be honest, this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I think you aren't understanding the issue. If I click into another textfield the focus changes immediately. However, if I click in a textfield and then use the picker, the focus doesn't change. How can I observe onChange(of: isFocused) if isFocused isn't changing? That will never fire. I ended up creating an @State bool and a custom get/set for the picker. In the set I am changing the bool to true. Then I am running the methods if !boolvar so that they do not run when the picker value is changed. It's a ridiculous bug in FocusState for macOS. This exact procedure works fine on iOS.